# Unexpected token in the expression '[' in xslt transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

So, my xml looks like this:

```
<Document Resolution="{X=300,Y=300}">
   ...
</Document>
```

I am trying to generate an `xml` with those resolution values. It should look like this:

```
<image xdpi="300" ydpi="300">
    ...
</image>
```

Now, my `xslt` file looks like this (image section):

```
<image>
    <xsl:attribute name="xdpi">
      <xsl:value-of select="/*/[substring-before(substring-after(@Resolution, 'X='), ',')]"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    ....
</image>
```

I am trying to extract the `X` value of the resolution. However, this is the message that I've got:

> Unexpected token in the expression '['

I tried removing the square brackets, but the complain got worse.

Is there a work around for this? or another way to extract the resolution value?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to use square brackets at all? It makes no sense in the situation you describe. In any case, a predicate is not a complete location step - IOW,  you cannot have a `/` slash just before `[` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use

```
<xsl:template match="Document">
  <image xdpi="{substring-before(substring-after(@Resolution, 'X='), ',')}" ydpi="{...}">...</image>
</xsl:template>
```

For your approach you would need

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(/*/@Resolution, 'X='), ',')"/>
```